# Calling preventDefault on DOM element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, preventdefault

I am currently in the process of creating an MVC4 web application, and I seem to have run into a weird issue. I have created a unordered list with some list items in it, and their respective anchor tags, in which I am going to be able to click, that will return the respective **/CONTROLLER/ACTION** view.

```
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="ajax" href="/Test/One"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="ajax" href="/Test/Two"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="ajax" href="/Test/Three"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="ajax" href="/Test/Four"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
   </div>

   <div id="body">
   </div>
```

I have then created some jQuery to call when you click either of the anchor tags, looking for a class of "ajax", and if you are to click the anchor tag, it will then run another function called GetContent, passing through the **HREF** value of the anchor tag, which will be used as the path for the ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ajax").click(function () {
        var path = $(this).attr("href");
        GetContent(path);
    });
});

function GetContent(path) {

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#body").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

I have heard of a function you can call, called **preventDefault** I believe. I am finding that I am not sure when to call this preventDefault to override the click of the anchor tag.

I did try placing it into a couple of places, but with no luck... I am finding at the moment I am able to click any of the anchor tags, and the default action occurs, it simply returns the whole website with the new view loaded. However if I open up the console in google chrome developer tools, and call the function GetContent, passing through the path I am expecting, it will then call the function, return the ajax, and update my web page.

If someone is able to point out where I am supposed to call the preventDefault function that would be great.

Comment: *"I have heard of a function you can call, called preventDefault I believe."* I, too, have heard rumours of such a function. There have been multiple reports of it being seen in the underbrush of the web. Or, wait, **[in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)**. And lo! The example in the documentation is preventing the default action of a link. Golly.

Comment: use `return false;` in the click handler or just pass a param in the function(e) and use `e.preventDefault()` just after the click handler function.

Comment: Thanks T.J, really appreciated the sarcasm... I am only new to jquery so give me a break...

Thank you Jai, appreciate the help.

Comment: @OhTehNoes: It takes an hour, tops, to read [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end, and it saves you a huge amount of time in the long term (or even in the medium term). I strongly recommend it. (Lest you get the wrong impression: I'd've also *answered* the question, but Rafael already had.) (BTW, if you want people to be notified that you've commented to them, you need to use the `@` sign.)

Comment: @t.j.crowder, thank you, I will go ahead and read the documentation. I appreciate that you got back to me in a positive manner, I'm sure you understand that being new to a language isn't always the easiest, and sometimes simple mistakes are made. Nonetheless, cheers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, sorry, didn't realize it had case sensitivity.

Comment: @OhTehNoes: *"sorry, didn't realize it had case sensitivity"* I don't think it does. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preventDefault` is a method of `event` object. You get the reference to `event` object as first param of the click event handler…

```
$(".ajax").click(function (event) {
    var path = $(this).attr("href");
    GetContent(path);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Rafael, I appreciate the help, this is exactly the sort of answer I was hoping for.

Comment: It still does seem as though it does not work correctly... I still see the whole page refresh and the url change to match the normal request. Which does not happen when I simply call the GetContent function using the console by itself.

Comment: This can mean many things. Some code part throws error before reaching `event.preventDefault` call. Or the click handler is not attached to the links. The second one you can easily check by putting `alert('test')` just before the line `var path = ...`. The second one, you have to check error console in your browser. In other cases, we would need a live example so we can click through it.

Comment: thanks for the tips, I will go and investigate, and will get back to you.